# Eigen3 : dynamic matrix along one dimension only : failure to contruct

Tags: matrix, constructor, eigen3

I can easily define a matrix type of fixed lines number and undefined columns number :

```
  typedef Matrix<double, 6, Dynamic> dMat6rowsNCols;
  dMat6rowsNCols M1;
```

But I couldn't figure out how to instanciate it, those attempts don't compile :

```
  M1.Zero(4);
  M1 = dMat6rowsNCols::Zero(4);
```

May I ask you some hints ?

Cheers

Sylvain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ac22f79b812fa564061042407f2ba8f5b) of `DenseBase::Zero(Index)`:

> This is only for vectors (either row-vectors or column-vectors), i.e. matrices which are known at compile-time to have either one row or one column.

You have to use `DenseBase::Zero(Index, Index)`:

```
M1 = dMat6rowsNCols::Zero(6, 4);
```

If you are using the current Eigen trunk you can use `Eigen::NoChange` for some functions, e.g.

```
M1.setZero(Eigen::NoChange, 4);
```

As a side note: Calling `M1.Zero` does not call the member function that sets all coefficients to 0 but is a less common way of calling the static function [`DenseBase::::Zero`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ae41a9b5050ed27d9e93c82c9c8622cd3). You are probably looking for [`M1.setZero`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#af230a143de50695d2d1fae93db7e4dcb).

Comment: Thanks a lot dtell,

Comment: I 've noticed that DenseBase::Zero(Index, Index) worked porperly, but semantically, I felt queasy to call a 2 dimension parameters method on a matrix which one dimension is fixed.

Comment: If you feel so, submit a feature request to Eigen ;-)

Comment: I tested to instanciate my 6xN matrix with a dMat6rowsNCols::Zero(7, 4) and it throws an exception. Hence it seems to be consolidated.